# Show Custom Post Type values in Wordpress grid view

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have created a custom post type in WordPress as shown in figure.
[image]
What i want is to show the values eneterd in this custom post in the grid view of admin panel. Now the admin panel is only showing the Post title, date and comment images but i want to show the Pair2,buy sell and activity fields values as entered in my custom post . I have searched alot but couldn't find any solution. How should i go about it in WordPress?
[image]

**EDIT**
Here is how i am making my custom post

```
   <?php
if( ! function_exists( 'quote_create_post_type' ) ) :
  function quote_create_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
      'name' => __( 'ForexPair' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'ForexPair' ),
      'add_new' => __( 'Add Pair Entry' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Pairs' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Pair' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Pair' ),
      'new_item' => __( 'New Pair' ),
      'view_item' => __( 'View Pair' ),
      'search_items' => __( 'Search Pairs' ),
      'not_found' => __( 'No pair found' ),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No pair found in trash' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent pair' )
      //'menu_name' => default to 'name'
    );
    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'supports' => array(
        'title'
      ),
      'register_meta_box_cb' => 'quote_add_post_type_metabox'
    );
    register_post_type( 'quote', $args );
    //flush_rewrite_rules();

  }
  add_action( 'init', 'quote_create_post_type' );


  function quote_add_post_type_metabox() { // add the meta box
    //add_meta_box( 'quote_metabox', 'quote_metabox', 'quote', 'normal' );
    add_meta_box( 'quote_metabox', 'Pair Entries', 'quote_metabox', 'quote', 'normal' );
  }


  function quote_metabox() {
    global $post;
    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="quote_post_noncename" id="quote_post_noncename" value="' . wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the data if its already been entered
    $quote_post_entryprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_quote_post_entryprice', true);
    $quote_post_stoploss = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_quote_post_stoploss', true);
    $quote_post_pairname = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_quote_post_pairname', true);
    $quote_post_buysell = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_quote_post_buysell', true);
    $quote_post_activity = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_quote_post_activity', true);
    $quote_post_takeprofit = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_quote_post_takeprofit', true);
    // Echo out the field
    ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gripforex.com/wp-content/themes/Forsy/select2.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gripforex.com/wp-content/themes/Forsy/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gripforex.com/wp-content/themes/Forsy/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gripforex.com/wp-content/themes/Forsy/select2.js"></script>
  <style>
  .lbl{
  width: 86px;
display: block;
line-height: 20px;
  }
  </style>
    <div class="width_full p_box">
      <p>

        <label class="lbl">Pair:</label>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2({

      matcher: function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0; }
});
    });
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#e2").select2({
      matcher: function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0; }
}); });
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#e3").select2({
      matcher: function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0; }
}); });
    </script>

  <select name="quote_post_pairname" id="e1" style="width:144px;">
  <option value="AUD/CAD" <?php if($quote_post_pairname=="AUD/CAD") echo "selected"; ?> >AUD/CAD</option>
  <option value="AUD/CHF" <?php if($quote_post_pairname=="AUD/CHF") echo "selected"; ?> >AUD/CHF</option>



  </select></p>
        <p>
        <label class="lbl">Buy Sell
          <select name="quote_post_buysell" id="e2" style="width:144px;">
            <option value="Buy" <?php if($quote_post_buysell=="Buy") echo "selected"; ?> >Buy</option>
            <option value="Sell" <?php if($quote_post_buysell=="Sell") echo "selected"; ?> >Sell</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </p>
        <p>
        <label class="lbl">Activity
          <select name="quote_post_activity" id="e3" style="width:144px;">
            <option value="Get Ready" <?php if($quote_post_activity=="Get Ready") echo "selected"; ?> >Get Ready</option>
            <option value="Active" <?php if($quote_post_activity=="Active") echo "selected"; ?> >Active</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </p>      
      <p>
        <label class="lbl">Entry Price<br>
          <input type="text" name="quote_post_entryprice" class="widefat" value="<?php echo $quote_post_entryprice; ?>">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p><label class="lbl">Stop Loss<br>
          <input type="text" name="quote_post_stoploss" value="<?php echo $quote_post_stoploss; ?>" class="widefat" />
        </label>
      </p>
      <p><label class="lbl">Take Profit<br>
          <input type="text" name="quote_post_takeprofit" value="<?php echo $quote_post_takeprofit; ?>" class="widefat" />
        </label>
      </p>      
    </div>
  <?php
  }


  function quote_post_save_meta( $post_id, $post ) { // save the data

    if( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['quote_post_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
      return $post->ID;
    }

    // is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )){
      return $post->ID;
    }

    $quote_post_meta['_quote_post_entryprice'] = $_POST['quote_post_entryprice'];
    $quote_post_meta['_quote_post_stoploss'] = $_POST['quote_post_stoploss'];
    $quote_post_meta['_quote_post_pairname'] = $_POST['quote_post_pairname'];
    $quote_post_meta['_quote_post_buysell'] = $_POST['quote_post_buysell'];
    $quote_post_meta['_quote_post_activity'] = $_POST['quote_post_activity'];
    $quote_post_meta['_quote_post_takeprofit'] = $_POST['quote_post_takeprofit'];
    // add values as custom fields
    foreach( $quote_post_meta as $key => $value ) { // cycle through the $quote_post_meta array
      // if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // don't store custom data twice
      $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // if $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
      if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, FALSE ) ) { // if the custom field already has a value
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
      } else { // if the custom field doesn't have a value
        add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
      }
      if( !$value ) { // delete if blank
        delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $key );
      }
    }
  }
  add_action( 'save_post', 'quote_post_save_meta', 1, 2 ); // save the custom fields
endif; // end of function_exists()


if( ! function_exists( 'view_quotes_posts' ) ) : // output
  function view_quotes_posts( $num = 4, $do_shortcode = 1, $strip_shortcodes = 0 ) {

    $args = array(
      'numberposts'     => $num,
      'offset'          => 0,
      //'category'        => ,
      'orderby'         => 'menu_order, post_date', // post_date, rand
      'order'           => 'DESC',

      'post_type'       => 'quote',

      'post_status'     => 'publish',
      'suppress_filters' => true,
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    global $wpdb;

 $querystr = "select $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
  WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'quote'
  ";


    $html = '<table><tr><th>Pair</th><th>Action</th><th>Status</th><th>Entry Price</th><th>Stop Loss</th><th>Take Profit</th></tr>';
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $meta_entryprice = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_quote_post_entryprice', true );
      $meta_stoploss = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_quote_post_stoploss', true );
      $meta_pairname = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_quote_post_pairname', true );
      $meta_buysell = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_quote_post_buysell', true );
      $meta_activity = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_quote_post_activity', true );
      $meta_takeprofit = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_quote_post_takeprofit', true );


      $html.='<tr>';
      $html .= '

          <td>'.$meta_pairname.'</td>
          <td>'.$meta_buysell.'</td>
          <td>'.$meta_activity.'</td>
          <td>'.$meta_entryprice.'</td>

          <td>'.$meta_stoploss.'</td>

          <td>'.$meta_takeprofit.'</td>
        ';
      $html.='</tr>';
    }
    $html .="</table>";
    $html = '<div class="wrapper">'.$html.'</div>';
    return $html;
  }
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: How did you register those custom fields? Are you using a plugin to do that?

Comment: @Sven No plugin.

Comment: @Sven see the update.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `manage_edit-${post_type}_columns` filter combined with the  `manage_${post_type}_posts_custom_column` action. Check the [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_%24post_type_posts_custom_column#Examples) within the Codex and deconstruct it step by step.

First make sure to enter the right name of your registered custom post type. You registered the post type with the name `quote`.

Second define the columns you want to add (see `set_custom_edit_quote_columns`) and allocate the appropriate values (see `custom_quote_columns`).

You should end up with something like this:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-quote_columns', 'set_custom_edit_quote_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_quote_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_quote_columns', 10, 2 );

function set_custom_edit_quote_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns['pair'] = __( 'Pair' );
    $columns['buysell'] = __( 'Buy Sell' );
    $columns['activity'] = __( 'Activity' );

    $columns['entryprice'] = __( 'Entry Price' );
    $columns['stoploss'] = __( 'Stop Loss' );
    $columns['takeprofit'] = __( 'Take Profit' );

    return $columns;
}

function custom_quote_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'pair' :
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_quote_post_pairname', true );
            break;

        case 'buysell' :
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_quote_post_buysell', true );
            break;

        case 'activity' :
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_quote_post_activity', true );
            break;

        case 'entryprice' :
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_quote_post_entryprice', true );
            break;

        case 'stoploss' :
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_quote_post_stoploss', true );
            break;

        case 'takeprofit' :
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_quote_post_takeprofit', true );
            break;

    }
}
```